# Dijkstra's algorithm which executes relaxation m times

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

In Dijkstra's Algorithm a **relaxation** is called *at most* **m times** (where m = #edges). I'm trying to figure out some concrete graph example, which relaxation is indeed executed m times. I understand that a relaxation happens every time when a cheaper path to a given node is found, but I can't really "visualize" such a case.

Comment: Since you initialize all vertices to `infinity` during initialization - a tree does exactly `m` relaxations - regardless of the weights.

Comment: Oh, of course! Thanks, amit!And what about Dijkstra's Algorithm using a Fibonacci-Heap? In which case would the DecreaseKey function be called m times? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Depending on implementation, but assuming you initialize the heap with n-1 elements (element per vertex, except the root), each with the value `infnity` - again, in a tree, it will be called exactly `m` times, since each element is initialized as `infinity`, and since there is a single path from the source to each node - each vertex will "discover" a new node and will cause the DecreaseKey.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, a tree is an example. An example with cycles is a graph on n vertices (where n is odd) that has the following edges:

(1, 2) of cost 1

(2, 3) of cost 1

(1, 3) of cost 10

,

(3, 4) of cost 1

(4, 5) of cost 1

(3, 5) of cost 10

...

(n - 2, n - 1) of cost 1

(n - 1, n) of cost 1

(n - 2, n) of cost 10

Dijkstra's algorithm from vertex 1 will always relax the expensive 1->3, 3->5, 5->7, 7->9, ... (n - 2)->n edges first, and then will find the longer but cheaper paths.

The given graph is a good example of why you need a priority queue at all in Dijkstra's algorithm. On random graphs, using a simple queue and just pushing vertices back after every edge relaxation tends to work very fast, but such an algorithm would run in exponential time on this case.